# Consulta SQL de todas las preguntas salvo las que la columna "respuestasCorrectas" de la otra tabla sea igual a 4

Tags: mysql, sql

El objetivo de la consulta es que muestre todas las filas de la tabla "preguntasOperarioDeServicios"; **salvo** las que en "respuestaCorrecta" tenga un valor superior a 3 **y salvo** que en la tabla "respuestasTestUsuario" no se mencione ese numeroPregunta.

SENTIDO DE LA APLICACIÓN PARA ENTENDER EL CONTEXTO:

Se pretende que si un usuario responde una pregunta bien 4 veces, se entiende que se lo ha aprendido, por lo que el programa va sumando. Entonces la consulta no debe mostrar las preguntas si en "respuestasCorrectas" hay un valor mayor que 3.

PROBLEMA:
Con la consulta que muestro, me salen todas las preguntas que aparecen en la tabla respuestasTestUsuario, pero no todas las que no se mencionan en la tabla "respuestasTestUsuario".

CONSULTA:

```
SELECT * 
       FROM preguntasOperarioDeServicios 
       INNER JOIN respuestasTestUsuario 
             ON preguntasOperarioDeServicios.numeroPregunta=respuestasTestUsuario.numeroPregunta 
       WHERE idUsuario LIKE 30 
             AND respuestasTestUsuario.modalidadPreguntas LIKE 'operarioDeServicios' 
             AND respuestasTestUsuario.respuestasCorrectas<4
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ejemplo, ya que numeroPregunta 1 tiene como respuestaCorrecta 4, no se debe seleccionar la pregunta 1. Pero si la pregunta 2 y 3 y 4(también aunque no esté en esta tabla) y 5(también aunque no esté en esta tabla) y 6(también aunque no esté en esta tabla), etc... Pero como en la tabla respuestasTestUsuario no se hace referencia a las numeroPregunta 4,5,6, etc, la consulta no me las devuelve.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero haberme explicado, no es fácil de explicar. ;)

Comment: En vez de inner join proba usando left join

Comment: tampoco sale con LEFT JOIN el resto de preguntas. Sólo salen las mencionadas en la tabla "respuestasTestUsuario". Gracias de todos modos. ; )

Comment: ¿Podrías editar la descripción del problema? Por ejemplo, dice: "Con la consulta que muestro, me salen todas las preguntas que aparecen en la tabla **respuestasTestUsuario**, pero no todas las que no se mencionan en la tabla "**respuestasTestUsuario**"." ¿es correcto esto? Además, si lo que quieres es las preguntas que esten en ambas tablas, ya probaste con un FULL OUTER JOIN?

Comment: Con los datos de ejemplo que das, no saldría ninguna respuesta si filtras por la columna `respuestasTestUsuario.modalidadPreguntas` el valor `'operarioDeServicios'`. Pero si filtras por `preguntasOperarioDeServicios.modalidadPregunta` si se puede producir el resultado que buscas. Confirmame si es correcta mi lectura y veo de escribir una respuesta. Un saludo.

Comment: Mmm igual no me he explicado bien. Se trata al final de a un select restar otro select. Algo así: [(SELECT numeroPregunta FROM preguntasOperarioDeServicios) - (SELECT numeroPregunta FROM preguntasOperarioDeServicios WHERE respuestasCorrectas LIKE 4)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución es restar a una select, otra select con el contenido que queremos descartar.

```
SELECT DISTINCT numeroPregunta 
  FROM preguntasOperarioDeServicios 
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT numeroPregunta 
                    from respuestasTestUsuario 
                   WHERE preguntasOperarioDeServicios.numeroPregunta=respuestasTestUsuario.numeroPregunta 
                     AND respuestasCorrectas >3)
```

¡Funciona perfecto! ;)